# List of posts with reaction GROUP BY reaction type

Tags: mysql, sql, adonis.js

I need Sql query for this case
here is my code  here is my code

here is my controller query

my `query` is:

`Post.query().preload('reactions')`

here is my  `model` relation

```
@hasMany(() => Post,{
    localKey :'id',
    foreignKey : 'reaction_id',
   
    onQuery: (query) => {
      query.select('id','reaction','chat_id',
         Database.raw('Count(*) as total_likes')
       )
       .groupBy('reaction')
      
    }
  })

  public reactions : HasMany<typeof Post>
```

`posts` table columns

```
id,
post
```

reactions table columns

```
id , 
user_id , 
reaction, 
post_id
```

For my case I need the data in the below format

Any one please give me raw query for this case ?

```
post_lists=[
           {
            id:1,
            post:'Hello everyone',
            reactions:[
                {
                    reaction:'like',
                    total_count:2
                },
                {
                    reaction:'love',
                    total_count:2
                }
            ]
            
          },
          {
            id:1,
            post:'Hello everyone',
            reactions:[
                {
                    reaction:'like',
                    total_count:2
                },
                {
                    reaction:'angry',
                    total_count:2
                }
            ]
            
          },
          .........
      ]
```

In my case my query return wrong result

Comment: Please don't just ask us to solve the problem or code the solution for you. 
Beginners are welcome, but we expect ___some effort from you___ to solve your own problem before asking a question. So show us your best effort. 
___SO is not a free coding service___, although we are very willing to help you fix issues with code you have written.

Comment: You cannot build that data structure from a query without also using some programing language, what are you using

Comment: https://codeshare.io/1YLN4m

Comment: [**Please Never** post images or off site links of code, data or error messages](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2310830). Please edit your question and include copy/paste the text into the question, formatted. 
This is so that we can try to reproduce the problem without having to re-type everything, and your question can be properly indexed or read by screen readers.